# c # and Comm Ports

Tags: c#, vb6, serial-port

Hey all i am trying to turn an A/V reciever on and off this the following RS232 command:

```
 @MAIN:VOL=Down & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)
```

This works just fine in my VB6 app:

```
 MSCommAV.CommPort = 4
 MSCommAV.RThreshold = 1
 MSCommAV.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
 MSCommAV.RTSEnable = True
 MSCommAV.PortOpen = True
 MSCommAV.Output = "@MAIN:VOL=Down" & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)
```

However i can not seem to get it working in my C# app:

```
 PCComm.CommunicationManager commAV = new PCComm.CommunicationManager();
 commAV.Parity = "None";
 commAV.StopBits = "One";
 commAV.DataBits = "8";
 commAV.BaudRate = "9600";
 commAV.PortName = "COM4";
 commAV.CurrentTransmissionType = PCComm.CommunicationManager.TransmissionType.Text; //.Hex
 commAV.OpenPort();
 commAV.WriteData("@MAIN:VOL=Down" + "\r" + "\n"); //Vol DOWN
```

I think the reason why its not working is the "\r" and "\n" replacing the vb6 Chr$(13) & Chr$(10).

CommunicationManager.cs: http://snipt.org/xmklh

Comment: What is `PCComm.CommunicationManager`?

Comment: I don't know anything about using serial ports in C#, but you don't need string concatenation to put a CRLF at the end of a string.  Just write `"@MAIN:VOL=Down\r\n"`.

Comment: @vcsjones: added the CommunicationManager code.

Comment: @Wyzard: What if i have code like this: **MSCommProj.Output = Chr(33) & Chr(137) & Chr(1) & Chr(80) & Chr(87) & Chr(48) & Chr(10)** How would that work using your method?

Comment: You can translate all those to backslash codes in the same way you translated `Chr$(13)` and `Chr$(10)` to `\r` and `\n` respectively.  My point is that you don't need plus signs and a separate pair of quotation marks for each control character.  `"Foo"+"\r"+"\n"` is the same as `"Foo"+"\r\n"` is the same as `"Foo\r\n"`.

Comment: What is the model and manufacturer of the AV equipment?  Marantz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what `PCComm.CommunicationManager` is. However, it's fairly simple to communicate via Serial without any special APIs. This C# code is the equivalent of the VB6 code:

```
var port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.RtsEnable = true;
port.Open();
port.Write("@MAIN:VOL=Down\r\n");
port.Close();
```

**EDIT**:

It's possible that your `CommunicationManager` is failing because it is not setting the `RtsEnable` property to `true`. Your VB6 code is doing that on line 4.

Comment: I have updated my OP with the CommunicationManager.cs code. Also, how would i do a write for **MSCommProj.Output = Chr(33) & Chr(137) & Chr(1) & Chr(80) & Chr(87) & Chr(48) & Chr(10)** type of code?

Comment: You can insert any character in a string with its hex code.  For example, 33 in hexadecimal is 21.  A character sequence of 33, 13, 10 would therefore be "\u0021\u000d\u000a".  If you prefer to avoid calculating hex literals, you can also cast ints: ((char)33).ToString() + (char)13 + (char)10.  If I were planing to use that approach, I'd write a params array function to handle the concatenation.