# CHAR comm port commands

Tags: c#, vb6

I am trying to use the following to send over an RS232 connected projector to turn it on:

```
commProj.Parity = "None";
commProj.StopBits = "One";
commProj.DataBits = "8";
commProj.BaudRate = "19200";
commProj.PortName = "COM6";
commProj.CurrentTransmissionType = PCComm.CommunicationManager.TransmissionType.Text; //.Hex
commProj.OpenPort();
commProj.WriteData((char)33 + (char)137 + (char)1 + (char)80 + (char)87 + (char)49 + "\n"); //turn on proj
```

Problem being is that it doesnt work.

I have done this with a VB6 port and it works just fine:

```
 public static PCComm.CommunicationManager commProj = new PCComm.CommunicationManager();

 MSCommProj.CommPort = 6
 MSCommProj.Settings = "19200,N,8,1"
 MSCommProj.PortOpen = True 
 MSCommProj.Output = Chr(33) & Chr(137) & Chr(1) & Chr(80) & Chr(87) & Chr(49) & Chr(10)
```

What am i missing?

David

CommunicationManager.cs: http://snipt.org/xmklh

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What type is `commProj`.  It's not a System.IO.Ports.SerialPort which is the .Net class for interfacing with serial ports, since that doesn't have a WriteData method

Comment: Updated my OP. Please take a look :o)

Comment: You are obviously missing some context. I'm not aware of any `WriteData()` method of any COM port related class in .net. You might want to tell us how you are writing your data to the COM port.

Comment: Isn;t this pretty much exactly the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005141/c-and-comm-ports)?

Comment: @Deanna: Didnt want to confuse anyone. That was **c # and Comm Ports** while this is just focusing on one thing, **CHAR comm port commands**

Comment: @StealthRT, can we look at this from a different direction maybe? Do you have any documentation on what the actual command that you want sent is? Translating between VB6 and C# seems to be causing confusion.

Comment: @Chris Haas: updated OP with manual for the projectors rs232c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the manual helps a lot. Try changing the `CurrentTransmissionType` to `TransmissionType.Hex` and sending the string `21890100000a`

```
commProj.CurrentTransmissionType = TransmissionType.Hex;
commProj.WriteData("21890100000a");
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, that was "connection check". Use `2189015057310a` for `on` and `2189015057300a` for `off`.

Comment: Didnt do anthing as well. Was that to turn it on or off?

Answer (score 1):

The plus(+) operator for char's doesn't concatenate the values it adds them.  So you end up passing "387\n" to write data.

You need to create a char array and then convert that to a string instead:

```
commProj.WriteData(new string(new char[] { (char)33, (char)37, (char)1, (char)80, (char)87, (char)49, '\n' }));
```

Comment: A byte[] is almost certainly required.  And the RTS and DTR signals should be turned on.  I would personally avoid a serial port interface that accepts a baudrate as a string.

Comment: @Hans Passant: RTS and DTR  were commented out of the VB6 program and it still works there.

Comment: Yes, it enables handshaking by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of object commProj is (specifically) but my guess is that the problem comes from casting each numeric value to a char.  A char is 2 bytes in size.  I recommend either trying to write a Byte array with your data in it, or concatenating a string with these chars and then converting the string to ascii text.

Comment: Updated my OP. Please take a look :o)